# java enum in different versions and updations

Tags: java, enums

I am using jre 6 now. Earlier, I was using javasdk1.4 but as I searched in Internet, found that enum is supported in 1.5 or higher version. So, I first updated jre to latest version and then now how to update j2sdk1.4 .

When I am using echo %PATH%

path showed is  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin"

But I can't set path to this location as 'javac' here is not recognizable..

My enum code i am not posting but is verified that it is correct.. Here, I am facing problem of setting path and updating j2sdk 1.4 even after jre updated to latest Version.

Note: I want to set path using command-prompt and Path command not using environment Variable.

I am using windows Xp

Comment: Are you sure you want to use java 1.4 (JRE -or- JDK)???...it is about a decade old now.  1.7 is the latest.

Comment: I have intalled latest one now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`javac` is not included in the JRE, it's just a runtime environment (Java Runtime Environment) used to run Java applications, nothing more.

Download a JDK (Java Development Kit) instead.

Comment: I have installed JDK latest version and noe enum programs  are running ...                                                         But Now I have in C: folder j2sdk1.4 and in location C:\Program Files\Java   ----   j2re 1.4 , jdk1.7 , jre6 and jre7 folder....                                                     Please tell me I need to remove older versions or they should remain as it is?          My enum programs problem is resolves all updates are installed but want to know is memory is unnecessary used for keeping these older versions What to do? Thanks...